# Como remover acento em Python?

Tags: python

Em R realizaria desta desta forma `iconv('Arapeí', to="ASCII//TRANSLIT")`, então, há alguma forma simples de fazer isso em Python?

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86940/discussion-on-question-by-marcio-mocellin-como-remover-acento-em-python) - Sobre votos, há uma breve explicação no [Tour], e tem mais detalhes para entender o funcionamento do chat em [Help]. - Ainda, no que diz respeito a duplicatas, o que determina o fechamento são as respostas que cubram as situações (no caso mencionado, há resposta dada lá que menciona exatamente o unidecode.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use unidecode:

`$ pip install unidecode`

```
from unidecode import unidecode
print(unidecode('Arrepieí'))
Arrepiei

str1 = 'café'
print(unidecode(str1))
cafe
```

Answer (score 6):

Use unidecode:

```
from unicodedata import normalize

source = 'Arapeí'
target = normalize('NFKD', source).encode('ASCII','ignore').decode('ASCII')
print(target)
```